# How can I view firebase cloud function logs older than 1 month

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have found that an error occurred in my app over a month ago.  It is most likely due to an issue with a firebase cloud function which I have added logging to.
Unfortunately via the firebase control panel or GCP I can't view logs older than one month.

Is there any way to view these?

If there is not is there any way to export and save these to file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it as follows.  Thanks to @Neelavar for pointing me in the right direction.
More information here:
[Log retention in Stackdriver GCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51942237/log-retention-in-stackdriver-gcp)

-- Run as admin

VScode on windows

Right click the shortcut or app/exe

Go to properties

Check "Run this program as an administrator"

```
-- Install gcloud Alpha (as admin)
gcloud components install alpha

-- List all projects (optional)
gcloud projects list

-- Set current project
gcloud config set project my-project

-- Check correct project selected (optional)
gcloud config get-value project

-- Update retention period
gcloud alpha logging buckets update _Default --location=global --retention-days=365
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't see it [in the console](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs#using_the_firebase_console), then it's not available.  You can [use the Firebase CLI to view/print logs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs#using_the_firebase_cli), but only recent entries.

Comment: I don't really know.  I could also be limited based on total size.