# Can I repopulate Logs to Stackdriver?

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, stackdriver

Hi supposing I have a sink from StackDriver to Google Cloud Storage for Archiving Purposes. Once the retention period of the logs on StackDriver is over, can I use the logs that land on Google Cloud Storage to populate Again StackDriver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In GCP, it is not possible to transfer the older logs from sink destination (Pub/Sub, Cloud Storage, or BigQuery) to Cloud logging.

The retention period is 30days in Cloud logging by default, however you can now create [custom retention](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/storage#custom-retention)  between 1 day and 3650 days. You can follow this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61291214/10415226) for more information about custom retention in Cloud Logging.